# Different notifications for different contacts

Tags: sms, notifications

im going abroad and im going to set up some twitter text alerts for people i follow so i dont have to use data. But doing this will give me constant text alerts.

Is there a way i can have the texts from 86444 go into my inbox but not notify me whilst having texts from other numbers notify me in the usual way?

I have an app called tasker which i assume might be able to do something like this if it helps

Answer (score -1):

Try custom messaging apps like GO SMS PRO or Handcent SMS.

These will allow you to customize the notification alerts for incoming messages from specific numbers!

Hope this helps! :)